# WCF : there was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wcf

I used [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks) link to learn WCF programming

I used the sample code in that link that was for connection between client and server. Now I want to convert that console applications to WPF but I get this error when I run client (of course I run server before running client) :

> *There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse that could accept the message. This
>   is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.*

Also I should say that sample code does not have any `app.config` file.

In `MainWindow.xaml` file for client :

```
[CallbackBehavior( ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,UseSynchronizationContext=false )]
public partial class MainWindow : Window,ICallbacks
{
    public void MyCallbackFunction(string callbackValue)
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher=Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action(
        () => textBox1.Text = callbackValue ) );
        //     MessageBox.Show( "Callback Received: {0}",callbackValue );
    }
    IStringReverser _channel;
    [ServiceContract( SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract = typeof( ICallbacks ) )]
    public interface IStringReverser
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string ReverseString(string value);
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindow myCallbacks = this;
        var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
           myCallbacks,
           new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
           new EndpointAddress(
              "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse" ) );
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( new WaitCallback(
            (obj) =>
            {
                _channel = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            } ) );
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _channel.ReverseString( "Hello World" );
    }
}
public interface ICallbacks
{
    [OperationContract( IsOneWay = true )]
    void MyCallbackFunction(string callbackValue);
}
```

In `MainWindow.xaml` file for server :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
       typeof( StringReverser ),
        new Uri[]{
      new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
        } ))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint( typeof( IStringReverser ),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse" );

            host.Open();

            MessageBox.Show( Properties.Resources.Service_is_available__Press__ENTER__to_exit_ );
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
                 CallbackContract = typeof( ICallbacks ) )]
public interface IStringReverser
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
}

public interface ICallbacks
{
    [OperationContract( IsOneWay = true )]
    void MyCallbackFunction(string callbackValue);
}

public class StringReverser : IStringReverser
{
    public string ReverseString(string value)
    {
        char[] retVal = value.ToCharArray();
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = value.Length - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            retVal[idx++] = value[i];

        ICallbacks callbacks =
     OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbacks>();

        callbacks.MyCallbackFunction( new string( retVal ) );

        return new string( retVal );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your server and your client run on the **same machine**? The `NetNamedPipe` binding **only** works on the same machine..

Comment: Arash, are you writing the Interface for the service twice? IStringReverser should only be written once in a separate dll so the exact interface can be shared by both the server and the client. The fully qualified namespace can make a difference, it's not just about the name of the interface alone.

Comment: Yes they are in same machine,also i tested with NetTcpBinding too but no success

Comment: @Despertar:Can you explain me more?

Comment: Also have you been able to connect to a service before without all the duplexing? If not you want to start with a barebone minimal example so that know you can connect. Then go back and add the duplex and callbacks on top of that. Secondly if you host with TCP it would be easier to verify it is listening by typing in cmd.exe `netstat -ano | findstr 1234` where 1234 is the port you are hosting on. That is the first thing you want to verify is that the server is even listening for connections before you try to connect to it.

Comment: yes,I also tested that console application and it worked without any problem,ok now i will test this command

Comment: @Despertar: i did not specified any port number in my code,so how should i know the port number that i am connecting with?thanks

Comment: @Arash While using NamedPipe on local machine, it is implemented via Memory Mapped File (MMF) so, port number has not been used in your sample.

Comment: @autrevo: Ok thanks,so i cannot test desperter commend line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem Solved So Easy,

All The Problem was that i mistakenly close connection after click on button in server!

Comment: Awesome, By this time I have executed your code, thrice and it worked fine at my side.   However I couldn't understand your MyCallbackFunction implementation at client side. Why do you need to use Dispatcher and BeginInvoke ?

Comment: please read this link : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-callbacks-hanging-wpf-applications